# How to calculate percent by row and annotate 100 percent stacked bars

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, stacked-chart, plot-annotations

I need help adding the percent distribution of the total (no decimals) in each section of a stacked bar plot in pandas created from a crosstab in a dataframe.

Here is sample data:

```
data = {
    'Name':['Alisa','Bobby','Bobby','Alisa','Bobby','Alisa',
            'Alisa','Bobby','Bobby','Alisa','Bobby','Alisa'],
    'Exam':['Semester 1','Semester 1','Semester 1','Semester 1','Semester 1','Semester 1',
            'Semester 2','Semester 2','Semester 2','Semester 2','Semester 2','Semester 2'],
     
    'Subject':['Mathematics','Mathematics','English','English','Science','Science',
               'Mathematics','Mathematics','English','English','Science','Science'],
   'Result':['Pass','Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Pass','Pass','Fail','Fail','Pass','Pass','Fail']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display(df)
     Name        Exam      Subject Result
0   Alisa  Semester 1  Mathematics   Pass
1   Bobby  Semester 1  Mathematics   Pass
2   Bobby  Semester 1      English   Fail
3   Alisa  Semester 1      English   Pass
4   Bobby  Semester 1      Science   Fail
5   Alisa  Semester 1      Science   Pass
6   Alisa  Semester 2  Mathematics   Pass
7   Bobby  Semester 2  Mathematics   Fail
8   Bobby  Semester 2      English   Fail
9   Alisa  Semester 2      English   Pass
10  Bobby  Semester 2      Science   Pass
11  Alisa  Semester 2      Science   Fail
```

Here is my code:

```
#crosstab
pal = ["royalblue", "dodgerblue", "lightskyblue", "lightblue"]
ax= pd.crosstab(df['Name'], df['Subject']).apply(lambda r: r/r.sum()*100, axis=1)
ax.plot.bar(figsize=(10,10),stacked=True, rot=0, color=pal)
display(ax)
    
plt.legend(loc='best', bbox_to_anchor=(0.1, 1.0),title="Subject",)

plt.xlabel('Name')
plt.ylabel('Percent Distribution')

plt.show()
```

[image]

I know I need to add a `plt.text` some how, but can't figure it out. I would like the percent of the totals to be embedded within the stacked bars.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's try:

```
# crosstab
pal = ["royalblue", "dodgerblue", "lightskyblue", "lightblue"]
ax= pd.crosstab(df['Name'], df['Subject']).apply(lambda r: r/r.sum()*100, axis=1)
ax_1 = ax.plot.bar(figsize=(10,10), stacked=True, rot=0, color=pal)
display(ax)

plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.1, 1.0), title="Subject")

plt.xlabel('Name')
plt.ylabel('Percent Distribution')

for rec in ax_1.patches:
    height = rec.get_height()
    ax_1.text(rec.get_x() + rec.get_width() / 2, 
              rec.get_y() + height / 2,
              "{:.0f}%".format(height),
              ha='center', 
              va='bottom')
    
plt.show()
```

Output:

```py
Subject English Mathematics Science
Name            
Alisa   33.333333   33.333333   33.333333
Bobby   33.333333   33.333333   33.333333
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

- From `matplotlib 3.4.2` use [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html)

  - See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for a thorough explanation of using the method, and for additional examples.
  - Using `label_type='center'` will annotate with the value of each segment, and `label_type='edge'` will annotate with the cumulative sum of the segments.
- It is easiest to plot stacked bars using [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with `kind='bar'` and `stacked=True`
- **To get the percent in a vectorized manner** (without [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)):

  1. Get the frequency count using [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)
  2. Divide `ct` along `axis=0` by `ct.sum(axis=1)`

     - It is important to specify the correct axis with [`.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) and [`.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html).
  3. Multiply by 100, and round.

  - This is best done using `.crosstab` because it results in a dataframe with the correct shape for plotting the stacked bars. `.groupby` would require further reshaping of the dataframe.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.3.4`, `matplotlib 3.5.0`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# calculate the normalize value by row
ct = pd.crosstab(df['Name'], df['Subject'], normalize='index').mul(100).round(2)

# specify custom colors
pal = ["royalblue", "dodgerblue", "lightskyblue", "lightblue"]

# plot
ax = ct.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(10, 10), stacked=True, rot=0, color=pal, xlabel='Name', ylabel='Percent Distribution')

# move the legend
ax.legend(title='Subject', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')

# iterate through each bar container
for c in ax.containers:

    # add the annotations
    ax.bar_label(c, fmt='%0.0f%%', label_type='center')

plt.show()
```

[image]

- Using `label_type='edge'` annotates with the cumulative sum

[image]

#### `ct`

```
Subject  English  Mathematics  Science
Name                                  
Alisa      33.33        33.33    33.33
Bobby      33.33        33.33    33.33
```